# jQuery Validation errors with summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, summernote

I use a [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and a [summernote js](http://summernote.org/) library. I noticed that jquery validation plugin throws the errors to browser console and I can't understand, why?

I use follow lib versions:

- jQuery Validation: **1.15.0**
- Summernote: **0.8.1**

[**HERE IS A NOT WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kfj54gaz/2/)

Just open the browser console and try to type something using summernote and you will see errors like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery2210050014222928296052' of undefined
```

Also I noticed this problem does not occur when I use jquery validation 1.14.0 version

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zzyjqx01/1/)

The difference between these demos is a jquery validation plugin version. I want to find out what wrong with 1.15.0. Could anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: If the only difference is the version of the plugin, then [report the bug directly to the developer here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).  We're only here to assist you with code you've written, not troubleshoot or take bug reports for third-party code.

Comment: FYI, within the HTML markup, you do not need to put commas between HTML attributes.